# Merging two DEM rasters in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, dem, merge

I tried to merge two DEM-rasters without any overlapping parts using "Mosaic To New Raster" tool. However the value range of output raster doesn't look correct. Assuming that `(A1,B1)` and `(A2,B2)` are value ranges of the first and the second raster respectively, I was expecting value range of output be `(MIN(A1,A2),MAX(B1,B2))` but wasn't. I tried merging with different tool settings but I couldn't get expected result.

Is my expectation wrong? If not where do I make mistake?

[image]

Comment: Run statistics on all as suggested. In any case, cell statistics, maximum, works much faster on rasters without overlap, compared to mosaic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first easy thing is to re-run the build raster statistics to ensure you are using the most up to date statistics. If that has not fixed the value range then the source of the problem may be in the way you merge the rasters, the parameter that lets you pick merge type e.g. last,min,mean etc?